# RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxdatasources

This is a tableView in RxSwift
I am not able to configure the dataSource. There seems to be parameters missing for RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource, although this is strange as I follow the exact same code source of the [official docs](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources)

[Xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO8Ko.png)
Whenever I hit enter to autocomplete the closure. The closure remains blank.

[autocomplet not effectiv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY8Z8.png) 
I really don't know how to resolve this one

```
  let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel>() 



dataSource?.configureCell = { (ds: RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionOfCustomData>, tv: UITableView, ip: IndexPath, item: Article) -> NewsFeedCell in
                let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: ip) as! NewsFeedCell
                cell.configure(news: item)
                return cell
            }
            dataSource?.titleForHeaderInSection = { ds, index in
                return ds.sectionModels[index].header
            }

    let sections = [
        SectionOfCustomData(header: "First section", items: self.articles),
        SectionOfCustomData(header: "Second section", items: self.articles)
        ]

            guard let dtSource = dataSource else {
                return
            }
            Observable.just(sections)
                .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dtSource))
                .disposed(by: bag)

        }
```

SectionModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxDataSources

struct SectionOfCustomData {
    var header: String
    var items: [Item]
}
extension SectionOfCustomData: SectionModelType {
    typealias Item = Article

    init(original: SectionOfCustomData, items: [Item]) {
        self = original
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest RxDataSources 3.0 ? I believe the init method required a configureCell in previous versions.

Answer (score 7):

Your code seems fine, it might be a version problem as suggested in the comment, but you can easily solve it by moving the configurations in *init*
 like this:

```
let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel>(
        configureCell: { (dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item) -> NewsFeedCell in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedCell
            cell.configure(news: item)
            return cell
        },
        titleForHeaderInSection: { dataSource, index in
            return dataSource.sectionModels[index].header
        })
```

Everything else should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Declare you global `dataSource` as optional var:

```
var dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel>?
```

I assume that you are configuring the cell in `viewDidLoad`so:

```
let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel>(configureCell: { (ds: RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionOfCustomData>, tv: UITableView, ip: IndexPath, item: Article) -> NewsFeedCell in
                let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: ip) as! NewsFeedCell
                cell.configure(news: item)
                return cell
            }
            dataSource?.titleForHeaderInSection = { ds, index in
                return ds.sectionModels[index].header
            })
```

And here is the key part:

```
self.dataSource = dataSource
```